# How to refresh jstree when value of knockout observable arrays has been updated?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jstree

HTML code:

```
<div id="jstree_1">
<ul data-bind="foreach: KoObservableArray">
    <li data-bind="attr: {type: type}">
        <a href="#" data-bind="text: text"></a>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: children">
            <li data-jstree='{"icon":"glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"}' data-bind="attr: {id: id, type: type}">
                <a href="#" data-bind="text: text"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then I will build the jstree with below command:

```
$('#jstree_1').jstree({
'plugins': ["wholerow", "checkbox"]});
```

Everything works fine for first initialization.
After that, we update knockout observable array data (KoObservableArray), and we need to refresh the jstree to reflect the new data.

I tried:

```
$('#jstree_1').jstree(true).refresh();
$('#jstree_1').jstree("refresh");
```

But none of them works for me. Please help and advices :(

Added code example to demo my problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/mang/pyh9m7de/7/

After click on changeMenu, I expect the Jstree will be refresh to represent new data.

Answer (score 0):

Use **redraw(true)**

refresh only goes back to initial state.

Comment: I have tried that before but not working as well.   $('#jstree_1').jstree(true).redraw(true);

Answer (score 0):

OKay I managed to solve this.

You have 2 alternatives:

1) Reset the data of your jstree

```
$('#jstree_1').jstree(true).settings.core.data = self.KoObservableArray();
$('#jstree_1').jstree(true).refresh();
```

This method working in Chrome and Firefox, but not in my IE :(

2) ugly workarounds - working for me in all browser.

remove the jstree from HTML and re-add to the DOM

```
    var elem = document.getElementById('jstree_1');
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);

    var newElement = $("<div id='jstree_1'><ul data-bind='foreach: KoObservableArray'><li data-bind='attr: {type: type}'><a href='#' data-bind='text: text'></a><ul data-bind='foreach: children'><li data-jstree='{'icon':'glyphicon glyphicon-leaf'}' data-bind='attr: {id: id, type: type}'><a href='#' data-bind='text: text'></a></li></ul></li></ul></div>").appendTo("#jstree_parent");
    ko.applyBindings(viewmodel, document.getElementById("jstree_1"));

    $('#jstree_1').jstree({
        'plugins': ["wholerow", "checkbox"]
    });
```